# Client not receiving server output

Tags: java, client-server, client

I am getting snagged up on this server client program in java. My program gets to

```
System.out.println("Check1");
String name = in.nextLine();
```

in the `BoardServer` and then it just sits there and nothing gets sent to the client.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BoardServer {
    private static Scanner in;
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static int num = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final int SBAP_PORT = 8888;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SBAP_PORT);
        System.out.println("Waiting for players to connect...");

        while (true) {
            Socket s = server.accept();
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Check1");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Check2");
            String message = "Hello " + name + " you are player number " + num;
            num++;
            System.out.println("Check3");
            out.print(message);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("player connected.");
            Player client = new Player(s);
            Thread t = new Thread(client);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use , BufferedReader / Writer for i/o streams

Comment: So changing printwriter and Scanner to BufferReader and Writer will solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send the name to the server with :

```
out.print(name);
```

use

```
out.println(name);
```

to send it if you want to read it with `in.nextLine()` on the server. This should solve your problem.